# Hashtable to base64 conversion

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way out for converting hash table to base64 in PowerShell. Not sure that's possible or not. Can anyone help me on this?

Strings can be converted to base64 via byte. I'm seeing only string conversion examples.

Please help me to figure this out to proceed further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the hash to JSON. Convert the JSON to Base64.

```
$hash = @{key = "value"}

# encode
$json = $hash | ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 100 -Compress
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($json)
$b64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)   # => 'eyJrZXkiOiJ2YWx1ZSJ9'

# decode
$bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($b64)
$json = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($bytes)
$hash = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: `$json | ConvertFrom-Json` returns a `[PSCustomObject[]]` by default. Use: `-asHashTable` (which is only available from PowerShell 6.0). Basically you might convert *any* PowerShell object from and to Base64 if you use the *PowerShell* (de)serializer: [`[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($HashTable) `](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psserializer)

Comment: @iRon Good point - definitely useful if the receiving end of the serialization is PowerShell as well. Another point worth noting is that Base64 is a string. If the data can be converted to JSON (.i.e. "a string"), then that's where it should stop. Converting it further to Base64 adds nothing of value, but it increases the length of the string.